# git remote repository and ssh protocol

Tags: git, ssh

I have a git server and it has a user called git
For remote clients, they use git@gitserver to clone, push and pull.
For this to work, I need to give the password for user git.

Is there a better way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ssh key for authentication. Each user make their own ssh key pair and then the public keys are collected inside `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of the git user. After this is set up, users don't need to enter nor know the password of the git user.

Comment: and how will I tell who is behind a commit if everyone is coming as user git?

Comment: well.. each commit has author info (name/email)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you want each remote client/user to have his/her own login. You'll need each client to  create a private key, generate a public key (using PuTTYgen or similar), and then add the public key to your authorized keys.

[Here's](http://fclose.com/b/linux/366/set-up-git-server-through-ssh-connection/) a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

They should use the [ssh protocol](http://fclose.com/b/linux/366/set-up-git-server-through-ssh-connection/). The remote server needs to know each client's rsa key, and they won't need to enter the password for every remote action.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to solve this:

1. Let them create RSA keys and upload the public key for the git user account.
2. Install one of the open source applications designed for managing a private git server, such as [Gitosis](https://github.com/res0nat0r/gitosis), [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite), or [GitLab](http://gitlabhq.com/).